# extend runtime limit for a USUSP job

Tags: lsf

when I doing a calculation halfway, I just found the runtime limit 50:00 may not be sufficient. So I use $bstop 1234 to stop the job 1234 and try to modify the old runtime -W 50:00 to -W 100:00
Can you suggest a command to do so?

I tried

```
$ bmod -W 100:00 1234 
Please request for a minimum of 32 cores!
For more information, please contact XXX@XXX.
Request aborted by esub. Job not modified.

$ bmod [-W 100:00| -Wn ]  1234
-bash: -Wn]: command not found
100:00[8217]: Illegal job ID.
. Job not modified.
```

according to

```
[-W [hour:]minute[/host_name | /host_model] | -Wn]
```

from http://www.cisl.ucar.edu/docs/LSF/7.0.3/command_reference/bmod.cmdref.html

I don't quite understand the syntax, -Wn does it mean Wall time new

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

- The first command fails because LSF calls a the mandatory esub defined by your administrator to do some preprocessing on the command line, and this is returning an error. Here's the relevant quote from the page you linked:

> Like bsub, bmod calls the master esub (mesub), which invokes any
>   mandatory esub executables configured by an LSF administrator, and any
>   executable named esub (without .application) if it exists in
>   LSF_SERVERDIR.

- You're going to have to come up with a bmod command line that passes the esub checks, but that might cause other problems because some parameters (like -n I believe) can't be changed at runtime by default so bmod will reject the request if you specify it.
- The -Wn option is used to remove the run limit from the job entirely rather than change it to a different value.

Comment: Yes, you are right! For trying to specific the unchanged core number (-n 32), I get rejected as well. Thanks for clarification, so the only way left is to contact the admin. Just curious, next time if I want to submit a job, say $ bsub -n 32 -Wn < mpi.lsf , so it won't have run limit anymore. Is it?

Comment: No, the -Wn option is only available for bmod.  You can try something like 'bmod -Wn <jobid>' to remove an existing runtime limit from a job, but it'll be subject to the same rules the admin imposed on your earlier bmod attempt.

Comment: thanks you sam. I get response from the admin that only system pending jobs(haven't started) can perform this extension and in the cluster there is a hard time limit which I can't break.